# WebStorm auto completion does not work for React js

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm

I've created a project using `create-react-app`. I have switched my JavaScript language version to `React JSX` in `Preferences` | `Languages & Frameworks` | `JavaScript`.
But I still have unresolved variable warning and unresolved function warning.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide any example of your code where the warnings appear?

Comment: @uğuraydın `React.Component` or `ReactDOM.render` keywords. The problem is that autocompletion doesn't work for React features

Comment: Have you tried to restart webstorm after changing settings? :P

Comment: Did you `import React from 'react';`?

Comment: @Tomasz Tried, sure)

Comment: @Sulthan `import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css` Yes

Comment: for React 15.x+, this should work out of the box; for other versions, installing typings is required. see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24780#comment=27-2493973

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> To enhance code completion we recommend that you add a TypeScript
>   definition file for React with `npm install --save @types/react`

ref: [blog.jetbrains](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/10/working-with-reactjs-in-webstorm-coding-assistance/)

Comment: In addition you might also need `npm install --save-dev @types/react-dom`

Comment: I'm not getting suggestions after `this.state.`

Answer (score 26):

The simplest way to achieve correct code completion while developing any (not only react) app is to add support for required type scrip libraries via IDE itself. Assuming you using JetBrains IDE for web dev (may be not WebStorm but IntelliJ IDEA):

- go to Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S)  -> Languages & Frameworks
- expand JavaScript
- pick Libraries, you'll see something like this [image: webstorm js libraries setup]
- click Download...
- search for any libraries you need (you can just start typing lib name in libs list), then click Download and Install [image: download and install TS libraries]
- when using react, I suggest to add: react; react-dom; react-native (if you interested in mobile dev)
- click Apply when you done [image: added TS libraries]

commonly you don't need to restart IDE, changes will apply immediately.
**Happy coding!**

Comment: This is the most accurate answer that fits the coder needs

Answer (score 7):

On WebStorm, open `Preferences`, Expand the `Languages & Frameworks`, then expand `JavaScript`, click on `Libraries`. Click the `Add` button and add react to list of libraries.
Restart WebStorm.

Or

You do this:
You can add a TypeScript definition for React with  `npm install --save @types/react`

Comment: Probably an issue with your version of WebStorm.

Comment: How to add react to list of libraries? I cant see any option.

Comment: @Pratik have you tried naming your files with the `.jsx`(`.tsx`) extension?

Answer (score 0):

Also, for reference, according to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24780#comment=27-2681125 it is possible to solve it entirely within IntelliJ instead of running the `npm` command manually.

You can search for all the packages you need for the autocompletion.